# Ada - How do I split a string in two parts?

Tags: string, ada

If I create a subprogram of type function that for instance orders you to type a string of a particular length and you type `Overflow`, it's supposed to type the last half of the string, so in this case it would be `flow`. But on the other end if I type an odd number of characters like `Stack` it's supposed to type the last half of the string + the middle letter, so in this case it would be "ack".

Let me make it clearer (text in bold is user input):

Type a string that's not longer than 7 characters: `Candy`

The other half of the string is: `ndy`

```
     with Ada.Text_IO;         use Ada.Text_IO;
        with Ada.Integer_Text_IO; use Ada.Integer_Text_IO;

         function Split_String (S : in String) return String is 
   
      
   begin
      
      Mid := 1 + (S'Length / 2);
      
      return S(Mid .. S'Last);
      
   
   end Split_String;
      
              
           S : String(1 .. 7);
           I : Integer;
        
        begin
          
   Put("Type a string that's no longer than 7 characters: ");
   Get_Line(S, I);
   Put(Split_String(S));
   
        end Split;
```

Let me tell you how I've been thinking. So I do a `Get_Line` to see how many characters the string contains. I then put `I` in my subprogram to determine if its evenly dividable by two or not. If it's dividable by two, the rest should be 0, thus it'll mean that typing out the other half of the string **+ THE MIDDLE CHARACTER** is not needed. If in all the other cases, it's not dividable by two I have to type out the other half of the string + the middle character. But now I stumbled upon a big problem in my main program. I don't know how type out the other half of a string. If a string contains 4 words I can just type out `Put(S(3 .. 4);` but the thing is that I don't know a general formula for this. Help is appreciated! :) Have a good day!

Comment: If your string length contains 6 characters then you want to output the slice (4..6). If the string length is 5 then you want to output (3..5). In both cases the beginning character to output on the last "half" of the string is  (length / 2) + 1.

Comment: Yeah I know that but how do I translate it to code. Whats the code to write out the LAST half of a string? Like is its something like

if Split_String(I) = True then
Put(S(Length'Last/2) 
elsif Split_String(I) = False then
Put(S(Length'Last/2)+1

end if;

Comment: For non-empty string we know that ‘Length = Last - First + 1’ and rearranged ‘First = Last - Length + 1’.

Comment: I updated my code (see post) but it still won't work and it's kind of apparent why it doesnt work because im only typing out the last character. I dont know how to type out the other half because no matter how i do it it wont comply.

Comment: If you index a string, like your S, with a single index, like S'Last, you will get a single character -- the character at that index. To get a sub-string you should use a range N .. M as the "index" -- actually this is called a "slice" of the string array. So you should do something like Put(S(3..4)), but with the 3 and 4 replaced by expressions that compute the indices of the first and last character in the second half of the string. In your case, both can be computed from the value of I.

Comment: Note also that after your Get_Line (S, I), the last character of the string that was read is not necessarily S(S'Last), but is S(I) (if I > 0). S'Last is the index of the last place (element) in the string variable, which in your case is 7, because you declared S with the index range 1 .. 7.

Comment: It's a nitpick, but try to avoid writing out conditionals like: `if cond then return true; else return false;` when you can just write: `return cond;`.

Answer (score 0):

You need a more general approach to your problem. Also, try to understand how `Get_Line` works for you.

For example, if you declare an input string with a large size such as

```
Input : String (1..1024);
```

You will have a string large enough to work with any likely input values.
Next, you need a variable to indicate how many characters were actually read by `Get_Line`.

```
Length : Natural;
```

The data returned by `Get_Line` will then be in the slice of the input string designated as

```
Input (1 .. Length);
```

Pass that slice to your function to return the second half of the string.

```
function last_half(S : string) return string;

last_half(Input(1..Length));
```

Now all you need is to calculate the last half of the string passed to the function `last_half`. The function will output a slice of the string passed to it. To find the first index of the last half of the input string you must perform the calculation

```
mid : Positive := 1 + (S'length / 2);
```

Then simply return the string `S(mid .. S'Last)`.

It appears that the goal of this exercise is to learn how to use array slices. Concentrate on how slices work for you in the problem and the solution will be very simple.

One possible solution is

```
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;

procedure Main is
   Input  : String (1 .. 1_024);
   Length : Natural;

   function last_half (S : in String) return String is
      Mid : Positive := 1 + (S'Length / 2);
   begin
      return S (Mid .. S'Last);
   end last_half;

begin
   Put ("Enter a string: ");
   Get_Line (Input, Length);
   Put_Line (Input (1 .. Length) & " : " & last_half (Input (1 .. Length)));
end Main;
```

Study how the solution uses array slices on the return value of Get_Line and on the parameter for the function last_half and on its return statement. It is also important to remember that the type String is defined as an unbounded array of character. This means that every slice of a string is also a string.

```
type String is array ( Positive range <> ) of Character;
```

Comment: The calculation above for mid works properly for even or odd length strings due to the way integer division works. For instance 5 / 2 returns 2. Integers have no fractional part. The result of 1 + ( 5 / 2) is 3. Thus the last half of "hello" will then be "llo". Similarly, a string with even number of characters works. The last half of "glue" will be 1 + ( 4 / 2) = 3 resulting in "ue".

Comment: It looks promising but I don't know how to implement into my program. Like where should my get line be etc

Comment: The Get_Line does not need to be moved in your program. You do not need a function to determine whether or not the length of the string is even. The math will take care of that.

Comment: I updated my code but it still won't work like how it should. I didn't really understand your instructions fully as I'm new to programming but you could have a look at my approach if you'd like.

Comment: I should saw your updated solution, I'm going to have a look at that.  A

Answer (score 0):

Aside from being an untidy mess, your latest code edit (as of 20:11 GMT on 15 Nov 2021) doesn’t even compile. Please don’t show us code like this! (unless, of course, that’s the problem).

I’d like to strongly suggest this alternate way of inputting strings:

```ada
declare
   S : constant String := Get_Line;
begin
   --  do things with S, which is exactly as long as 
   --  the input you typed: no undefined characters at
   --  the end to confuse the result, no need to worry
   --  about overrunning an input buffer
end;
```

With this change, and obvious syntactic changes, your current code will do what you want.